# copying every nth line to a new line

Tags: sed, awk

I have a txt file that I need to copy the 1st line of every four lines and print it onto the 3rd line of every four. And print this into a new txt file.
e.g

```
@CR5SM:00004:00029
TTTTCTCTTTCTTTCTT
+
>>>/>@99419BAAABB
@CR5SM:00005:00026
ATTATAGAGGGATAG
+
;969999999-4;BB
```

change it to this:

```
@CR5SM:00004:00029
TTTTCTCTTTCTTTCTT
+CR5SM:00004:00029
>>>/>@99419BAAABB
@CR5SM:00005:00026
ATTATAGAGGGATAG
+CR5SM:00005:00026
;969999999-4;BB
```

I have tried using Awk but cant seem to find the correct commands to do this.
Does anyone have any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^@/{a=substr($0,2)}/^\+/{$0=$0 a}1' file
@CR5SM:00004:00029
TTTTCTCTTTCTTTCTT
+CR5SM:00004:00029
>>>/>@99419BAAABB
@CR5SM:00005:00026
ATTATAGAGGGATAG
+CR5SM:00005:00026
;969999999-4;BB
```

You can redirect the output to another file by saying:

```
awk '/^@/{a=substr($0,2)}/^\+/{$0=$0 a}1' file > newfile
```

- We use the `substr` function to capture the lines that start with `@` from second character onwards until the end of the line.
- We look for lines that start with `+` (notice we escape it since it is a meta-character). Once we find that line, we append our captured line to the existing line.
- `1` at the end allows us to print the lines.

Comment: Elegant, but it relies on the _content_ of lines rather than their _index_.

Comment: @mklement0 Correct, but this appears to be some sort of bio-medical fasta output where dependency on content might pay off, especially when some proteins sequences overlap to multiple lines. Just a guess though. `:)`

Comment: Sounds good - just wanted to point it out; may be worth stating that in your answer.

Comment: @mklement0 Perhaps it's not required.  These are fasta files with rather specific output.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
awk '
 (NR-1) % 4 == 0 { l=substr($0,2); print; next } # save every 4th line (print & continue)
 (NR-1) % 4 == 2 { print $0 l; next }            # append saved line to every 3rd line (print & continue)
 { print }' \                                    # all other lines: print as is
 infile > outfile  # specify input file and redirect output to output file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;n;n;G;s/\n.//;n'  file
```

Copy the first line, print the first and second lines and append the first to the third removing the first character of the first, print it and the fourth line and repeat.